# Hide created at and modified at lines in the edit view

Tags: 2007

IS there a way to hide the created at and the modified at lines that appear when editing or previewing an item on a list? I want this changes to be kind of anonymous

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the info from the DOM with script, but it would still be there for a second as the page loads.

You could also customize the form and simply not show that information, which would be more "secure".

Finally, custom development, but that seems like overkill for your goal.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for answering so quickly. Your first 2 choices seem exactly what I need. I just need to know how I can customize the form, or how I can inject JavaScript into the page.

Comment: I've got lots of posts on my blog with examples and tricks.